# How to have multiple panels/tabs of the same thing (e.g. multiple swatch tabs)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, workflow, swatches

Is there a way to have two or even three panels/tabs of the same thing such as 3 swatch tabs? I was looking for a way to be able to switch between default and custom swatches instead of having them all mixed together in one single panel/tab.

Also, sometimes I'd like to see both swatch panels at the same time so I'd like to be able to make one swatch panel a tab and the other one a button.
I'm using Photoshop CC

Comment: AFAIK, Photoshop's swatch panel doesn't work like this. Newly loaded swatches either replace or are appended to the existing swatches. (FWIW, Illustrator's swatch panel works just as you've described. I frequently work with 2 or 3 different swatch sets loaded up in their own panel tabs.)

Comment: You might be able to use a CC Library as your second swatch panel, depending on what you need to put in it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to do what you want, but I know a way to have the swatches you want present. 
Place all the swatches you want in a grid (just grab an online grid and colour fill the squares to what you want) as a new layer, then colour pick from that.
I fully understand that this isn't exactly ideal, but it does allow the use of different swatch panels.
It would be nice if photoshop added the multiple swatch panels as a feature, but it's just wishful thinking at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I use Photoshop cc2015, and I ran into this problem. I deleted all of my default swatches (by pressing option and clicking on the swatches), and then I added all my most used colors to swatches. I clicked the drop down on the top right side of the swatch window, and clicked "save swatches". I then deleted the swatches and made swatches of the print colors I use, repeating the saving process with those swatches. Now, I can click on the dropdown at the top right of the swatches panel, and click "replace swatches" and choose whichever swatch file i want. It isn't as nice as tabs, but it is certainly easier than using an eye dropper every time I need to switch swatch panels.